# Multiple Criteria Filter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to filter out rows if a cell contains certain texts in column B for example i want to filter out a row if any cell in column B contains texts "Apple" or "China" the problem i am facing is - when i use spreadsheetapp.newfilterCritera.whentextcontains("text") it works for only 1 text but not for multiple texts. Please help me to solve the issue. my current code is :

```
function myFunction() {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sp = wb.getSheetByName("Test");

  var c1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains([
    "Apple",
    "China",
  ]);

  sp.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, c1);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zguB.png)

Comment: have you tried filter two times and then union results ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const values = [
    "Apple",
    "China",
  ];
const formula = '=OR(' + values.map(e=>`B2="${e}"`).join(',') + ')';
var c1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied(formula);
```

Reference:

[whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula)